# Line Terminator (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain to me what is a Line Terminator? I have trouble searching it online. It may be slightly irrelevant to the question but I would just like to know.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-line-terminators

Answer (score 2):

A line terminator is OS specific. This doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript. On windows a line is terminated by the control character sequence `\r\n`, On UNIX like systems, it is `\n`.

Recall that control characters aren't printable characters, so the `\r` and `\n` is conceptual, but usually they're put in string literals to represent the control character.

Comment: Thank you. That really helps me to understand much better than the ones i see in the internet

Comment: @JamesLess consider accepting the answer if you thought it was helpful.